# Custom Domain-Google Cloud function with HTTP triggers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dns

So we have made a google cloud function with an HTTP trigger.
My aim is not to include firebase in this project.

How can I use my custom domain to connect to google cloud function using cloud DNS or something equivalent?

I already tried using a CNAME record but it didn't work as expected.

The Aim is to avoid CROS when we invoke it using Javascript/JQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to map a custom domain to your HTTP/S triggered Cloud Functions is by using Firebase Hosting. There is no way to do so without using Firebase.

Comment: Even I feel the same, what I am doing is that , invoking cloud function using firebase hosting.

Comment: they should have supported CNAME , I wonder what stops them, or with cloud DNS as seen on AWS after the domain verification

Answer (score 0):

I belive @Frank is right, the way to go here is to use Firebase. But to improve GCP product or to have this feature in future, I would recommend creating a feature requests to support CNAME, you can create it under Compute --> [Create new Cloud Functions issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=0) or you could pick any of the more relevant [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=0)